# Cannot write to global variable from Python Scrapy method

Tags: python, class, scrapy, global-variables

I defined a scrapy method that I expect to write to a global variable:

I set a global variable with a placeholder value

```
currentTitle = 'unchanged global title'
```

Then I define the scrapy spider

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    currentClassTitle = 'unchanged class title'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            #here goes my list of urls to scrape
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        title=response.xpath('/html/head/title').getall()
        title=str(title)
        title=title[9:-10]
        print(title)
        #So far so good, the title is correctly extracted and printed
        #I intend to write the title to both global currentTitle variable
        # and to class variable currentClassTitle, using method update for the latter:

        global currentTitle
        currentTitle = title
        QuotesSpider.update(title)

    def update(value):
        QuotesSpider.currentClassTitle = value
```

What comes next is standard scrapy stuff which I'm not very familiar with, but has been working well until I stumbled with this issue

```
def crawl ():
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

    process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
    process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    time.sleep(2)

def run_spider(spider):
    def f(q):
        try:
            runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
            deferred = runner.crawl(spider)
            deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
            reactor.run()
            q.put(None)
        except Exception as e:
            q.put(e)

    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    result = q.get()
    p.join()

    if result is not None:
        raise result
```

Below is a function that triggers the scraper whenever any document of a particular Google Firestore collection has the value crawled: False (which it changes to True)

```
def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    docCounter = 0
    for doc in col_snapshot:
        print(u'{}'.format(doc.id))
        thisDoc_ref = db.collection(u'urls').document(doc.id)
        thisDoc_ref.update({u'capital': 'sample capital name'})
        thisDoc_ref.update({u'crawled': True})
        run_spider(QuotesSpider)
        sleep(5)
        #Just to ensure that I give the crawler enough time to process, the function sleeps after triggering the spider. 
        #Not the best practice, but good enough for testing functionality for the moment

        print(QuotesSpider.currentClassTitle)
#I get 'unchanged class title'

        print(currentTitle)
#I get 'unchanged global title'

        thisDoc_ref.update({u'title': currentTitle})
#I intend to store the document's title in Firestore using the value of currentTitle, which will not work
#because I cannot retrieve the value of title
```

Whatever works, obtaining the value of the title from class attribute *QuotesSpider.currentClassTitle* or global variable *currentTitle* will do the trick for me, but none of them work. I cannot seem to be able to update the value of any of them when running the spider.

Comment: Hi @Ivan! In python, if you want to modify a variable inside your class instance, you should do it as `self.currentClassTitle`. If you are doing `QuotesSpider.currentClassTitle` you are referring to the variable of the class, not the instance that you are using! I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your variable specific to your *instance* of your Python class inside one of its class methods, you want to use

```
self.currentClassTitle
```

Using `QuotesSpider.currentClassTitle` accesses the default class variable (when your class is not initialised)

More info here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/